# How do you get a border around the controlbox in ExtJS Modern?

Tags: extjs, extjs6-modern

So I've worked with ExtJS classic at work, but for a personal project I'm using the Ext6.6 Community Edition.

In classic there's automatically a border around the controlbox (the part of the field where you actually type a value). There's also a config (fieldStyle) that can be used to control that border if you want.

However in modern neither of these things exist. Textfields have no border around the controlbox and fieldStyle doesn't exist. The border and style configs place a border around the entire field, label and all, but I only want the border around the controlbox.

Please help!

Comment: Maybe it's the theme customization. Which modern kit theme are you using?

Comment: I was in modern-material...switching to modern-neptune fixed it, though it fubar'd a bunch of my other CSS, but that's fixable!

Sorry for the dumb question! :(